# SparseArray with width or height 0

Tags: list-manipulation, sparse-arrays

I can store the zero matrix (=module morphism) $R^2\overset{a}{\leftarrow} R^3$ as `a=SparseArray[{},{2,3}]`. But

- $R^0\overset{a}{\leftarrow} R^3$ stored as `a=SparseArray[{},{0,3}]`,
- $R^2\overset{a}{\leftarrow} R^0$ stored as `a=SparseArray[{},{2,0}]`,
- $R^0\overset{a}{\leftarrow} R^0$ stored as `a=SparseArray[{},{0,0}]`,

is no longer a SparseArray and contains no info about the dimensions of $a$. How can I remedy this?

Comment: Is there no other way than to store the dimensions in a separate list?

Comment: Mathematica represents tensors as nested lists. This means that representing zero-dimensional ones is not possible.  1x0 would be `{{}}` but 0x1 or similar is not possible (when a result would be this it usually gives us `{}`, a length-0 1-index tensor). While this applies to non-sparse arrays, it seems that it's SparseArray data structure stays consistent with this.